# Pandas: how to add missing columns to a DataFrame when assigning Series as row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of Pandas Series which are produced one at a time, and I want to assign each of them as a row in a DataFrame, with the columns of the DataFrame being the union of all Series index values.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# the names of all series are known in advance
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['A', 'B'])

# in reality there are many long series, not just two
a = pd.Series({'v':0, 'w':1, 'x':2, 'y':3}, name='A')
b = pd.Series({              'x':4, 'y':5, 'z':6}, name='B')

# generate and assign each series as one row in the frame
for row in (a,b):
    # create new columns - this is what I want to eliminate
    for column in row.index.difference(df.columns):
        df[column] = np.nan

    df.loc[row.name] = row

print(df)
```

This produces the desired result:

```
     v    w    x    y    z
A  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
B  NaN  NaN  4.0  5.0  6.0
```

But without the `for column` loop, it produces an empty DataFrame with no columns.

I am looking to eliminate the `for column` loop.  I don't know all the columns ahead of time.  I also hoped to assign `np.nan` to all the new columns in a vectorized way, but that doesn't work due to an old issue I submitted here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13658

Answer (score 1):

[**`pd.DataFrame.set_value`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html) will automatically add the columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

# in reality there are many long series, not just two
a = pd.Series({'v':0, 'w':1, 'x':2, 'y':3}, name='A')
b = pd.Series({              'x':4, 'y':5, 'z':6}, name='B')

# generate and assign each series as one row in the frame
for row in (a,b):
    for i, v in row.iteritems():
        df.set_value(row.name, i, v)

print(df)

     v    w    x    y    z
A  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
B  NaN  NaN  4.0  5.0  6.0
```

This is still a loop, but `set_value` is pretty zippy.

***time test***
***small data***

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
los = [pd.Series(1, [i], name=i) for i in range(10)]

stmt1 = """
for row in los:
    for column in row.index.difference(df.columns):
        df[column] = np.nan

    df.loc[row.name, row.index] = row
"""

stmt2 = """
for row in los:
    for col, value in row.iteritems():
        df.set_value(row.name, col, value)
"""

setup = """
from __main__ import df, los, np
"""

print(timeit(stmt1, setup, number=100))
print(timeit(stmt2, setup, number=100))

0.5426401197910309
0.01039268122985959
```

***large data***

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
los = [pd.Series(1, [i], name=i) for i in range(1000)]

stmt1 = """
for row in los:
    for column in row.index.difference(df.columns):
        df[column] = np.nan

    df.loc[row.name, row.index] = row
"""

stmt2 = """
for row in los:
    for col, value in row.iteritems():
        df.set_value(row.name, col, value)
"""

setup = """
from __main__ import df, los, np
"""

print(timeit(stmt1, setup, number=100))
print(timeit(stmt2, setup, number=100))

63.69273182330653
1.1242545540444553
```

Comment: As the comment says, in reality there are many series, not just two.  This solution will reallocate the DataFrame every time through the loop, which unless I'm missing something will result in very poor performance.

Comment: @JohnZwinck this is a great question and you've got me thinking... I'll let you know if I come up with something.

Comment: @JohnZwinck this should give you something to work with

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the multiple series as list to the [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series({'v':0, 'w':1, 'x':2, 'y':3}, name='A')
b = pd.Series({              'x':4, 'y':5, 'z':6}, name='B')

df = pd.DataFrame([a, b])
print(df)

    v    w    x    y    z
A   0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
B   NaN  NaN  4.0  5.0  6.0
```

Comment: I can't do this because I don't know have all the Series ahead of time.  They are produced one by one, and I want to populate the DataFrame from them without collecting a big list of all the Series first (which would at least double the total memory usage).